# How to filter elements from XML file

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I can read a xml file to the console. But I need only some elements from the xml file. Like
Sender Name, Postalcode, weight and value. Because now all the element from the xml file are returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `XDcoument` with `LINQ`

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load($"XMLFile1.xml");

var items = xdoc.Descendants("Parcel")
                .Select(xelem => new
                {
                    Name = xelem.Element("Sender").Element("Name").Value,
                    PostalCode = xelem.Element("Sender").Element("Address").Element("PostalCode").Value,
                    Weight = xelem.Element("Weight").Value,
                    Value = xelem.Element("Value").Value
                });

foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{ item.Name} - { item.PostalCode} - { item.Weight} - { item.Value}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But then I don't need all the other code? Because if I run your script I only get the name: Klaas
ykken groot B.V.
seti
Aad

Comment: @mightycodeNewton you dont need any other code. I have updated the post to get what is requried.

Comment: @mightycodeNewton, have updated with much simplified version. please have a look